# Pipenv not found on command line(WINDOWS)

Tags: python, cmd, terminal, pipenv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpFGA.png)

I have installed pipenv but when I try to use pipenv it says pipenv *not found*

I installed pipenv using *pip install pipenv*. And pipenv installed successfully. But when I try to use pipenv, pipenv is *not found* in the command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. right-click the "Windows" icon and select System.
2. Under the settings you will see the "Advanced system settings"
   [image]

And add your pipenv path to environment settings;
[image]

Finally close the current terminal and re-open then try again.